# Download Attachments and Salesforce Files from Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, code, remedyforce

I am trying to modify Visualforce code to allow for the download of an attached file to the Incident ticket.

Currently the file is listed with this code, but I need it to be a clickable download link. I have tried 2 code options which produce errors.

This code results in a clickable link, but the Action {!save} is not correct.

```
 </td>                    
                    <td> 
                        <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!incidentSelected}">
                            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!incidentSelected}">
                                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AttachmentList}" var="pitem" id="attList" columns="2" width="40px,60px">
                                    <apex:column headerValue="Action" >                         
                                        <apex:commandLink action="{!deleteAttachment}" title="Delete" value="DEL" >
                                            <apex:param value="{!pitem.Id}" name="idToDel" assignTo="{!pitemId}"/>
                                        </apex:commandLink>
                                    </apex:column>
                                    <apex:column headerValue="Attachment Name" >
                                    <apex:commandLink action="{!save}" title="Download" value="{!pitem.Name}" >
                                            <apex:param value="{!pitem.Name}" name="idToDownload" assignTo="{!pitemId}"/>
                                       </apex:commandLink>
                                    </apex:column>
                                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </td>                  
                </tr>
```

Does anyone know what the commandlink action should be to successfully trigger a download?

I've also tried this code which produces the following error:

```
        <td> 
                        <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!incidentSelected}">
                            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!incidentSelected}">
                                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AttachmentList}" var="pitem" id="attList" columns="2" width="40px,60px">
                                    <apex:column headerValue="Action" >                         
                                        <apex:commandLink action="{!deleteAttachment}" title="Delete" value="DEL" >
                                            <apex:param value="{!pitem.Id}" name="idToDel" assignTo="{!pitemId}"/>
                                        </apex:commandLink>
                                    </apex:column>
                                    <apex:column headerValue="Attachment Name" >
                                   <apex:page standardController="Attachment">
                                    <apex:outputLink
                                    value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download,
                                    attachment.id)}">
                                    Download Now!
                                    </apex:outputLink>
                                     </apex:page>
                                    </apex:column>
                                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </td>                  
                </tr>
```

**Error: Unknown property 'AttachmentStandardController.allDone'**

I'm unable to test the second code until I can resolve the error.

Finally, the Visualforce page shows the Attachment to the Incident ticket, but not the Salesforce files. How do I modify the code to show both Attachments and Salesforce files?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT - Added most of Controller code

Controller Code

```
public class ViewPTController {
  //vars
    public Boolean working {get;set;}
    public Boolean allDone {get;set;}
    public Boolean closeWindow {get;set;}
    public String textNote {get;set;}
    public String userId {get;set;} 

  //Project
    public Id pID {get;set;} //project id
    public String Project {get;set;}
    public String ProjectName {get;set;}
    public String DateOpened {get;set;}
    public String OpenedBy {get;set;}
    public String SubmittedBy  {get;set;}
    public String ClosedBy {get;set;}
    public String LastDateFixed {get;set;}
    public amc__Project__c selectedProject {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> optionsProject {get;set;}

    //StatusFilter
    public Id sfID {get;set;} //status id
    public String StatusFilter {get;set;}
    public BMCServiceDesk__Status__c selectedStatusFilter{get;set;}
    public Boolean statusFilterSelected {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> optionsStatusFilters {get;set;}

    //Incident
    public Id iID {get;set;} //incident id
    public Boolean incidentSelected {get;set;}
    public BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c theIncident {get;set;}
    public String IncidentDescription {get;set;}
    public String Incident {get;set;}
    public String IncidentNumber {get;set;}
    public Map<Id,BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> incMap {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> IncidentListFiltered {get;set;}

    //History
    public String History {get;set;}
    public HistoryItemWrapper[] theHistoryWrapper {get;set;}
    public List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__History> incidentActionHistorys {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> Historys {get;set;}
    public List<Attachment> attachmentItemHistory {get;set;}

    //Staff Assigned and Assignees
    public String Staff {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> optionsUsers {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> optionsOther {get;set;}
    public List<String> OtherEmails {get;set;}

    //Incident Status
    public Id sID {get;set;} //status id
    public BMCServiceDesk__Status__c selectedStatus {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> optionsStatus {get;set;}
    public String Status {get;set;}
    public List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> imList = new List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c>();

    //Attachments
    public List<SelectOption> attachmentSelectOptionList {get;set;}

    public Attachment attachmentItem;
    public String pitemId {get;set;}//parameter for attachment item
    public List<Attachment> attachmentItems {get;set;}

    //Notes
    public List<BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c> noteList {get;set;}

    //map and lists
    public Map<Id,BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> iM {get;set;}

    public List<BMCServiceDesk__Status__c> sL  {get;set;}

   public List<BMCServiceDesk__Status__c> sf  {get;set;}

    public List<BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c> ihl  {get;set;}

    public Map<Id,User> userList  {get;set;}

    public Map<Id,BMCServiceDesk__Status__c> statusMap  {get;set;}

    //init
    public ViewPTController(){
        incidentSelected = FALSE;
        statusFilterSelected = FALSE;
        working = TRUE;
        allDone = FALSE;
        IncidentNumber = '';
        IncidentListFiltered = null;
        pID = null;
        sID = null;
        sfID = null;
        DateOpened = '--';
        OpenedBy = '--';
        SubmittedBy = '--';
        ClosedBy = '--';
        LastDateFixed  = '--';
        userId = UserInfo.getUserId();

        theIncident = new BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c();
        optionsProject = new List<SelectOption>();
        optionsProject.add(new SelectOption('-- Select --','-- Select a Project --'));
        selectedProject = new amc__Project__c();
        optionsUsers = new List<SelectOption>();
        optionsUsers.add(new SelectOption('-- Select --','-- Select a Ticket --'));
        optionsOther = new List<SelectOption>();
        optionsOther.add(new SelectOption('-- Select --','-- Select a Ticket --'));
        optionsStatus = new List<SelectOption>();
        optionsStatus.add(new SelectOption('-- Select --','-- Select a Status --'));
        optionsStatusFilters = new List<SelectOption>();
        optionsStatusFilters.add(new SelectOption('-- Select --','-- Select a Status --'));
        optionsStatusFilters.add(new SelectOption('-- ALL --','-- ALL --'));
        incMap = im;
        iID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'); 

        IncidentMap = new Map<Id,BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c>(
        [SELECT Id, Name, Subject__c, Severity__c, Type_Of_Request__c, Application_Project__c, BMCServiceDesk__FKClient__c, BMCServiceDesk__FKOpenBy__c, BMCServiceDesk__FKStatus__c  
         FROM BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c WHERE BMCServiceDesk__state__c = TRUE AND Project_Name__c != null ORDER BY Name]);
      system.debug('init called IncidentMap set as new map');
        sl= [SELECT Id, Name FROM BMCServiceDesk__Status__c 
    WHERE BMCServiceDesk__appliesToIncident__c = TRUE AND BMCServiceDesk__inactive__c = FALSE ORDER BY BMCServiceDesk__state__c DESC];

        sf = [SELECT Id, Name FROM BMCServiceDesk__Status__c 
    WHERE BMCServiceDesk__appliesToIncident__c = TRUE AND BMCServiceDesk__inactive__c = FALSE ORDER BY BMCServiceDesk__state__c DESC];

 ihl = [SELECT Id,BMCServiceDesk__date__c, BMCServiceDesk__description__c FROM BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c 
                                                            ORDER BY BMCServiceDesk__date__c DESC];

            userList = new Map<Id,User>([SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE]);

        statusMap = new Map<Id,BMCServiceDesk__Status__c>([SELECT Id, Name FROM BMCServiceDesk__Status__c 
    WHERE BMCServiceDesk__appliesToIncident__c = TRUE AND BMCServiceDesk__inactive__c = FALSE ORDER BY BMCServiceDesk__state__c DESC]);


        if(iID != null){
            Incident = iID;
            theIncident = iM.get(Id.valueOf(Incident));
        }
    }

    public Map<Id,BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> IncidentMap{
        get{
            system.debug('called get on IncidentMap');
            //20190528--change loading im
            //im = new Map<Id,BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c>([SELECT Id, Name, Subject__c, Severity__c, Type_Of_Request__c, Application_Project__c, BMCServiceDesk__FKClient__c, BMCServiceDesk__FKOpenBy__c, BMCServiceDesk__FKStatus__c  
            // FROM BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c WHERE BMCServiceDesk__state__c = TRUE AND Project_Name__c != null ORDER BY Name]);
            if(im.size()<1)
            {
                getIncidentsMap();
            }
            //20190528--end
            system.debug('incidentmap size='+String.valueOf(im.size()));
            return im;
        }
        set
        {
            system.debug('called set on IncidentMap');
            im = value;
        }
    }

    public void getIncidentsMap()
    {
        IncidentMap=  new Map<Id,BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c>(
            [SELECT Id, Name, Subject__c, Severity__c, Type_Of_Request__c, Application_Project__c, BMCServiceDesk__FKClient__c, BMCServiceDesk__FKOpenBy__c, BMCServiceDesk__FKStatus__c  
             FROM BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c WHERE BMCServiceDesk__state__c = TRUE AND Project_Name__c =: ProjectName ORDER BY Name]);//2019520
        system.debug('called getIncidentsMap method to set IncidentMap for Project: '+ProjectName);
    }
    public class HistoryItemWrapper implements Comparable
    {
        cHistoryListItem chil;
        public HistoryItemWrapper()
        {
            chil = new cHistoryListItem();
        }
        public HistoryItemWrapper(cHistoryListItem paramchil) 
        {
            chil = paramchil;
        }
        public Integer compareTo(Object objcHistoryListItem) 
        {
            HistoryItemWrapper hiw = (HistoryItemWrapper) objcHistoryListItem;
            if (hiw.chil.cDate > this.chil.cDate) return +1;
            if (hiw.chil.cDate < this.chil.cDate) return -1;
            return 0; 
        }
   }

    public class cHistoryListItem 
    {
        public String cID {get; set;}
        public DateTime cDate {get; set;}
        public String cTitle  {get; set;}
        public cHistoryListItem ()
        {
            cID = '';
            cDate = system.now();
            cTitle = '';
        }
    }
//set Incident ID (theIncident.Id) before calling
    public List<BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c> IncidentHistorys
    {
        get{ 
            system.debug('entered property get IncidentHistorys');
            if(incidentHistorys == null)
            {
                incidentHistorys = new List<BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c>();
            }
            if(incidentHistorys.size() <1)
            {
                incidentHistorys= [SELECT Id,BMCServiceDesk__date__c, BMCServiceDesk__description__c,CreatedDate,CreatedById FROM BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c WHERE BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c =: iId ORDER BY BMCServiceDesk__date__c DESC];
            }
            return incidentHistorys;
        }
            set
            {
                incidentHistorys = value;
            }
        }

    public HistoryItemWrapper[] TheHistoryItemWrapper
    {
        get{
            if(theHistoryWrapper == null)
            {
                theHistoryWrapper = new List<HistoryItemWrapper>();
            }
            return theHistoryWrapper;
        }
        set{
            theHistoryWrapper = value;
        }
    }
    //set IncidentHistorys before calling
    public void getIncidentHistorys()
    {
        system.debug('entered getIncidentHistorys');
        if(IncidentHistorys != null)
        {
            for(BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c ih: incidentHistorys)
            {
                User historyUser = userList.get(ih.CreatedById);
                cHistoryListItem chl = new cHistoryListItem();
                chl.cID = ih.Id;
                chl.cDate = ih.CreatedDate;
                chl.cTitle = ih.CreatedDate +' | '+ historyUser.Name +' | '+ ih.BMCServiceDesk__description__c;
                TheHistoryItemWrapper.add(new HistoryItemWrapper(chl));
            }
        }
    }
    public void getAttachmentHistorys()
    {
        system.debug('entered getAttachmentHistorys');
        attachmentItemHistory = new List<Attachment>();
        attachmentSelectOptionList = new List<SelectOption>();
        attachmentSelectOptionList = getAttachments();
        attachmentItemHistory =attachmentItems;
        if(attachmentItemHistory != null){
            for(Attachment atc: attachmentItemHistory){
                User historyUser = userList.get(atc.CreatedById);
                cHistoryListItem chl = new cHistoryListItem();
                chl.cID = atc.Id;
                chl.cDate = atc.CreatedDate;
                chl.cTitle = atc.CreatedDate +' | '+ historyUser.Name +' | Attached File ' + atc.Name;
                TheHistoryItemWrapper.add(new HistoryItemWrapper(chl));
            }
        }
    }
    //helper method
    public List<String> getCleanName(String fieldName, String oldVal, String newVal)
    {
        List<String> cleanName = new List<String>();
        String tmpName = '';
        Boolean ck = true;
        String ckVal= '';
        String ckNVal ='';

        if(fieldName.indexOf('__FK') > 10)//contains an FK
        {
            tmpName = fieldName.mid(18,fieldName.length()-21);
            cleanName.add(tmpName);
            //cleanName.add('FALSE');//20190528--removed
            system.debug('__FK > 10::cleanName::tmpName='+tmpName);
            //return cleanName;//20190528--removed
        }
        else
        {
            //20190529 -- added for fields not conforming to __FK__  
            if(fieldName.indexOf('BMCServiceDesk__') > 0)
            {
                tmpName = fieldName.mid(16,fieldName.length()-19);
                cleanName.add(tmpName);
            }
            else
            {
                if(fieldName.right(3) =='__c')
                {
                    tmpName = fieldName.left(fieldName.length()-3);
                    cleanName.add(tmpName);
                }
                else  //20190529 -- end
                {
                    tmpName = fieldName.mid(16,fieldName.length()-19);
                    cleanName.add(tmpName);
                }
            }
        }
        system.debug('fieldName='+fieldName);
        system.debug('cleanName[0]='+cleanName[0]);
        system.debug('cleanName::tmpName='+tmpName);

        if(cleanName[0].length() > 1)
        {
            if(oldVal != null)
            {
                ckVal = string.valueOf(oldVal);
                if(ckVal != '')
                {
                    if(ckVal.Length() > 14 & ckVal.Length() < 19)
                    {
                         system.debug('getCleanName::oldVal!=null::ckVal='+ckVal);
                        ck = Pattern.matches('[a-zA-Z0-9]', ckVal);
                        system.debug('getCleanName::oldVal!=null::ckVal::ck='+ck);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ck=true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(ck==true & newVal != null)
            {
                ckNVal = string.valueOf(newVal);
                system.debug('getCleanName::ck==true::newVal!=null::ckNVal='+ckNVal);
                if(ckNVal != '')
                {
                    if(ckNVal.Length() > 14 & ckNVal.Length() < 19)
                    {
                        ck = Pattern.matches('[a-zA-Z0-9]', ckNVal);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ck=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            system.debug('getCleanName::else');
            ck = false;
        }
        if(ck==true)
        {
            system.debug('getCleanName::ck==true');
            cleanName.add('TRUE');
        }
        else
        {
             system.debug('getCleanName::ck==false');
            cleanName.add('FALSE');
        }
        //system.debug('cleanName ck='+ck);
        return cleanName;
    }
    //gets status value changes
    public void getIncidentActionHistorys()
    {
        List<String> cleanName = new List<String>();
        system.debug('entered getIncidentActionHistorys');
        system.debug(' getIncidentActionHistorys:iID = '+iID);
        incidentActionHistorys = new List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__History>();
        incidentActionHistorys = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate,CreatedById,ParentId,Field,OldValue,NewValue FROM BMCServiceDesk__Incident__History 
                                  WHERE ParentId =: iID ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
        if(incidentActionHistorys != null)
        {
            system.debug('getIncidentActionHistorys:incidentActionHistorys not null:iid='+iID);
            for(BMCServiceDesk__Incident__History iah: incidentActionHistorys)
            {
                //20190528--exclude BMCServiceDesk__UpdateCount__c
                if (iah.Field != 'BMCServiceDesk__UpdateCount__c')
                {
                    User historyUser = userList.get(iah.CreatedById);
                    system.debug('fieldname='+iah.Field);
                    String fieldName = iah.Field;
                    String oldValue ='';
                    if (iah.OldValue != null)
                    {
                        oldValue = string.valueOf(iah.OldValue);
                    }
                    String newValue = '';
                    if (iah.NewValue != null)
                    {
                        newValue = string.valueOf(iah.NewValue);
                    }
                    cleanName = null;
                    cleanName = getCleanName(fieldName,oldValue,newValue);
                     //20190530 -- added for Owner field
                    if(fieldName == 'Owner')
                    {

                        cleanName.Clear();
                        cleanName.Add(fieldName);
                        if(oldValue.substring(0,3)=='005')
                        {
                            cleanName.add('FALSE');
                        }
                        else{
                        cleanName.add('TRUE');
                        }
                    }//20190530 -- end
                    system.debug('cleanName[1]='+ cleanName[1]);
                    system.debug('cleanName.size=='+cleanName.size());
                    system.debug('cleanName:fieldName='+fieldName +' | oldValue='+oldValue+' | newValue='+newValue);
                    if(cleanName.size() >0)
                    {
                        if(cleanName[1] == 'TRUE')
                        {
                            String cleanFieldName = cleanName[0];
                            cHistoryListItem chl = new cHistoryListItem();
                            chl.cID = iah.Id;
                            chl.cDate = iah.CreatedDate;
                            chl.cTitle = iah.CreatedDate +' | '+ historyUser.Name +' | Changed Field [' + cleanFieldName +'] from ' + oldValue +' to ' + newValue;
                            TheHistoryItemWrapper.add(new HistoryItemWrapper(chl));
                        }
                    }
                }//20190528--end exclusion
            }
        }
        system.debug('exited getIncidentActionHistorys');
    }
    //properties
    //BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c: Action History in Salesforce views
    public List<SelectOption> getHistorys()
    {
        system.debug('entered getHistorys');
        theHistoryWrapper = null;
        Historys = new List<SelectOption> ();
        if(theIncident != null){
            //notes
            system.debug('getHistorys:theIncident.Id='+theIncident.Id);
            iID = theIncident.Id;
            getIncidentHistorys();
            //action history
            getIncidentActionHistorys();
            //attachments
            getAttachmentHistorys();

            //sort
            if(theHistoryWrapper != null)
            {
                theHistoryWrapper.sort();
                List<cHistoryListItem> sortedList = new List<cHistoryListItem> ();
                for(HistoryItemWrapper hiw : theHistoryWrapper)
                {
                    Historys.add(new SelectOption(hiw.chil.cID,hiw.chil.cTitle));
                }
            }

            else
            {
                Historys.add(new SelectOption('No History','No History'));
            }
        }
        return Historys;
    }

    public List<Attachment> AttachmentList{
        get{
            if(attachmentItems == null){
                attachmentItems = new List<Attachment>();                
            }
            attachmentItems.clear();
            attachmentItems =[select Id, Name, Description, LastModifiedDate from Attachment where ParentId = :theIncident.Id order by Name];
            return attachmentItems;
        }

    }

    public Attachment attachment{
       get{
            if(attachmentItem == null)
                attachmentItem = new Attachment();
            return attachmentItem;
            }
    }

    //property methods

    public List<SelectOption> getAttachments()
    {
        system.debug('entered getAttachments');
        if(theIncident == null){
            attachmentSelectOptionList = new List<SelectOption>();
        }
        else{
            attachmentSelectOptionList = new List<SelectOption>();
            attachmentItems = new List<Attachment>();
            attachmentItems =[select Id, Name, Description, CreatedDate,CreatedById from Attachment where ParentId = :theIncident.Id order by Name];
            if(attachmentItems != null){
                for(Attachment atc: attachmentItems){
                    attachmentSelectOptionList.add(new SelectOption(atc.Id, atc.Name));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                attachmentSelectOptionList.add(new SelectOption('No Attachments','No Attachments'));
            }
        }
        return attachmentSelectOptionList;
    }
```

Comment: It might be also necessary to post VF Controller Code since VF errors are always coming in combination with controller + extensions

Comment: Thanks, where do I find the Controller Codes? In the page code or a separate file?

Comment: It is in separate file - apex class  -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_def.htm

Comment: Thanks, I've found the Apex classes - how do I know which one to modify?  <apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="ViewPTController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"> Am I looking for one called ViewPTController?

Comment: Controller code added, what I think is the relevant portions.